# Ignoring signature in JWT

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, jwt

I have an web application that is using OpenId Connect. I created a self signed certificate but it is still not signed by a CA.
How can I ignore the signature validation?

This is what I have so far:

```
SecurityToken validatedToken = null;

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler {
    Configuration = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration {
        CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None
    },
};

TokenValidationParameters validationParams =
    new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Issuer"],
        AudienceValidator = AudienceValidator,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true
    };

return tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwtToken, validationParams, out validatedToken);
```

It throws the following exception:

> IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve
>   SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier\r\n    (\r\n
>   IsReadOnly = False,\r\n    Count = 1,\r\n    Clause[0] =
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause\r\n
>   )\r\n', \ntoken:
>   '{\"typ\":\"JWT\",\"alg\":\"RS256\",\"kid\":\"issuer_rsaKey\"}.{\"iss\":...

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes I did. It was not supposed to check the signature, JWT does it for us and it is not supposed to have the private key of the Identity Provider in the client side. So there is not need to check signature.

Comment: The following change covers a workaround - https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-csharp/commit/c5334cfed0c6fe11992062b08249bc5b691b7092 if it'd be helpful, I can provide an answer explaining in detail

Comment: @Bonomi, it doesn't require the private key for validation, only the public key which you can get from your `jwks` endpoint.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932596/ignore-jwt-bearer-token-signature-i-e-dont-validate-token#

Answer (score 18):

Don't ignore the signature, **this is dangerous!**

Even if you use a self-signed certificate, you will be able to use the public key for signature validation.

Since you are using OpenId Connect, you should be able to get the *public key* for your signing certificate by heading over to `/.well-known/jwks`.

Then you can setup your validation parameters like this:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(yourPublicKeyGoesHere));

var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { 
    IssuerSigningTokens = new[] { new X509SecurityToken(certificate) }  
};
```

After that, you can call `ValidateToken`:

```
SecurityToken token;
var claimsPrincipal = handler.ValidateToken(encodedToken, validationParameters, out token);
```

**You really want to ignore the signature?**

Remember, if you do, how do you know someone didn't tamper with the data inside the token? You could easily decode the base64 url encoded payload and change the subject. And if you rely on that in your application, you'll be in trouble (**hint: someone accessing someone else data**)

**You REALLY, REALLY want to ignore it?**

You can use `ReadToken` and just skip every validation there is:

```
var badJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler()
                 .ReadToken(encodedMaliciousToken) as JwtSecurityToken;
```

**DON'T do that though, it's bad practice.**

Comment: why is it that setting `TokenValidationParameter.ValidateIssuerSigningKey` to false does not does the job of bypassing signature validation ?

Comment: @Veverke looking at the source code of [JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs), it does not honor `TokenValidationParameter.ValidateIssuerSigningKey` at all. It seems to have no impact as far as token validation is concerned.....

Answer (score 3):

```
public TokenValidationParameters CreateTokenValidationParameters()
{
    var result = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidIssuer = ValidIssuer,

        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidAudience = ValidAudience,

        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
        //IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecretKey)),
        //comment this and add this line to fool the validation logic
        SignatureValidator = delegate(string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters)
        {
            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);

            return jwt;
        },

        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,

        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
    };

    result.RequireSignedTokens = false;
    enter code here
    return result;
}
```