# WebApi call always unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I am implementing access token validation on my Asp .Net WebApi, but although I am trying to disable any kind of check, I always get `401 Unauthorized`.
I have only added the code that follows and the `Authorize` attribute in the controller:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters =
            new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                RequireSignedTokens = false,
                RequireExpirationTime = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = false,
                ValidateActor = false
            };

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            TokenValidationParameters = validationParameters
        });
    }
}
```

In addition this is the Global.asax

```
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

I am sure that the token I am using works, because if I  use ADFS validation instead of this manual validation the flow works correctly.

**UPDATE**
Enabling debug info I noted I'm getting the following error.

Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware Error: 0 : Authentication failed
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
    (
    IsReadOnly = False,
    Count = 1,
    Clause[0] = X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(Hash = 0x84371F65121DD3A5362C77EF61C5CC4EE5AD3807)
    )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I added diagnostic on Owin

```
  <system.diagnostics>
<switches>
  <add name="Microsoft.Owin" value="Verbose" />
</switches>
```

Then I added the `IssuerSigningToken` among the `TokenValidationParameters` since the middleware was trying to validate the token.
I found this solution thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35835672/2297037.