# Ignore JWT Bearer token signature (i.e. don't validate token)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an API that sits behind an API Gateway. The API Gateway validates the bearer token before passing the request along to the API.

My API the uses the the asp.net core 2.0 native authentication and claims based authorization framework. The grunt work of getting the claims from the JWT token is done by the middleware in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer`.

This middle ware can be configured to ignore the expiration date on the token and it is also possible to specify a local public key so it is not necessary to contact the token Authority to obtain one, but is it possible to just disable the signature validation on the token?

This would allow use of unsigned tokens for ad-hoc testing in development and prevent double validation (gateway and then API) in production.

Comment: I think if you clear the default token validator and provide your own ISecurityTokenValidator that skips any validation should do it. https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs

Comment: @Eli Algranti Could find any way to do this? I'm currently stuck on the same issue.

Comment: Just to share my design. I'm using this approach as well to disable the double validation at gateway and api level. I'm using nginx+ as the api gateway, identityserver4 to generate the token. Api gateway will do the validation. This will remove the need of token validation to be done in the api level(which it can be coming from .net , java or etc)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try this. Finally, I got it to work after so much of trying.

```
public TokenValidationParameters CreateTokenValidationParameters()
{
    var result = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidIssuer = ValidIssuer,

        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidAudience = ValidAudience,

        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
        
        //IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecretKey)),
        //comment this and add this line to fool the validation logic
        SignatureValidator = delegate(string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters)
        {
            var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);

            return jwt;
        },

        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,

        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
    };

    result.RequireSignedTokens = false;

    return result;
}
```

**Edit**:

For dotnet 8 and higher you should replace `var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);` in SignatureValidator with `var jwt = new JsonWebToken(token);`

As [@thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339137/thomas) mentioned you also can use lamba:

```cs
SignatureValidator = (token, _) => new JsonWebToken(token)
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/8.0/securitytoken-events

Comment: I've moved on from the project so I can't validate your answer, so I'll accept it and take your word for it. Someone else may find this useful.

Comment: I struggle this for 2 days of nonstop testing and finally get it to work. woo laa...

Comment: This works great. thanks for sharing what you spent 2 days on so we don't have to. It is really odd you need to do sooo much just do disable one validation

Comment: This is also working in asp.net core 3.1, thank you for the research ... saved me a ton of time

Comment: This solution doesn't feel Claims. Is it possible to force smth to fill them?

Comment: ValidateTokenReplay = false is also needed, it's guaranteed that the User object and Claims will be initialized. Also, ValidIssuer(not a bool flag) and ValidAudience are optional for our case if we want to skip validation.

Comment: This worked for us, in our case we wanted to ONLY validate the lifetime so we deactivated the rest

Comment: While this does work for me, I do not really understand what is happening here. Is there some explanation somewhere?

Comment: Works on .NET 5 as well. In case you only want to skip the key validation you just need to set ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false and assign the SignatureValidator = (token, _) => new JwtSecurityToken(token);
Similar to what is shown in this answer.

Comment: Works on .NET 6 as wel

Comment: Tested with .Net 6. I wanted to use the claims from the token after the API gateway passed it to the API. This saved my day. Thankyou.

Comment: Has anyone validated that this is indeed secure?

Answer (score 6):

You may setup token validation using `JwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters`. You could check all available parameters from [the class definition](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/TokenValidationParameters.cs#L118).

> Contains a set of parameters that are used by a `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandler` when validating a `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken`.

Set All `ValidateXXX` and `RequireXXX` bool properties to false if you want to disable validation at all:

```
.AddJwtBearer("<authenticationScheme>", configureOptions =>
{
   options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateActor = false;
   options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
   options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false;
   ...
}
```

---

As an another option you can override the default token signature validation by setting own implementation to `JwtBearerOptions.SignatureValidator`:

```
// Gets or sets a delegate that will be used to validate the signature of the token.
//
// Remarks:
//  If set, this delegate will be called to signature of the token, instead of normal
//  processing.
public SignatureValidator SignatureValidator { get; set; }
```

where `SignatureValidator` delegate is defined as:

```
public delegate SecurityToken SignatureValidator(string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am already using `JwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters` to disable expiration time validation, however I could not find good documentation for this class. Do you know which option (if any) disables checking the token signature? I was hoping to find someone who has already actually done and checked this.

Comment: @EliAlgranti have update post. You could read about each property from class definition ([source code](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/TokenValidationParameters.cs#L118) is available)

Answer (score 4):

I was able to clean up the code a bit, showing that we can just change the flag and with a bit more consistency when setting the flags.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        o.SaveToken = true;
        o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            RequireSignedTokens = false
        };
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer and there are a few more, please expose the Pros of yours. And try to explain your code a little bit.

Comment: Hopefully, that is better @DavidGarcíaBodego. It is definitely more of a code clean up.

Answer (score 1):

For dotnet 8 or higher you should use `JsonWebToken` instead `JwtSecurityToken`

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
    {
        opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateActor = false,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
            ValidateLifetime = false,
            ValidateTokenReplay = false,
            SignatureValidator = (token, _) => new JsonWebToken(token)
        };
    });
```

For earlier versions change `SignatureValidator` to:

```cs
SignatureValidator = delegate(string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters)
{
    var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(token);

    return jwt;
}
```