# Do not validate JWT expiration in tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, nunit

I'm writing an integration test for my web service with JWT authentication. I'd like to test it with a token received from the real service. The problem is real tokens expire in 1 hour.

A possible way is to set `options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime` inside `AddJwtBearer` of class `Startup` below.
However, `Startup` class is a also a code to be tested, so I don't want to change or replace it for testing.

Is there a neat way to test all JWT validation logic except expiration?

My project code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddAuthentication("JWT")
            .AddJwtBearer("JWT", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://my-real-identity-server.com/";
                options.Audience = "...";
                // I don't want to disable lifetime validation in real life
                // options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false;
            });
        
        // Other stuff
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) => app
        .UseRouting()
        .UseAuthentication()
        .UseAuthorization()
        .UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
}

public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("/validate")]
    public string Get() => "success";
}
```

My test code:

```
public class HostBuilderTests
{
    private IHost testHost;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancel;
    private HttpClient client;

    [SetUp]
    public async Task ShouldReturnStatus()
    {
        testHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                webBuilder
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseTestServer())
            .ConfigureServices(services => services
                .AddLogging(b => b.ClearProviders().AddNUnit()))
            .Build();

        cancel = new CancellationTokenSource(10000);

        var server = testHost.Services.GetRequiredService<IServer>()
            .ShouldBeOfType<TestServer>();
        await testHost.StartAsync(cancel.Token);
        client = server.CreateClient();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public async Task TearDown()
    {
        await testHost.StopAsync(cancel.Token);

        client.Dispose();
        testHost.Dispose();
        cancel.Dispose();
    }

    [Test]
    [TestCase("<<JWT token copied from the real service>>")]
    public async Task StatusShouldBeOk(string realToken)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", realToken);

        using var response = await client.GetAsync("/validate", cancel.Token);
        response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a bunch of different "Validate..." properties inside your AddJwtBearer lambda. You're already setting two for the Authority and Audience. Is one of them talking about "lifetime" or "expiration"? For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59014327/1043380

Comment: @gunr2171 good point, see my edits.

Comment: Are you hard coding all your options in AddJwtBearer, or are you setting them through configuration (which you should)?

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, I do. So the solution is to use different app config for the test project, great!

Comment: i would be wary of doing that - you could introduce security bugs if you do a different configuration.

Comment: @DanielA.White I see. Config should also be tested. Copy-pasting real config to the test project and adding `"ValidateLifetime": false` is fragile way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a simple way to manage options for authentication handlers:

> An authentication scheme is a name which corresponds to:
>
> - An authentication handler.
> - Options for configuring that specific instance of the handler.

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

So it suffices to post-configure `JwtBearerOptions` specifying the authentication scheme name `"JWT"` as options instance name in the test setup:

```
testHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    // other setup
    .ConfigureServices(services => services
        .PostConfigure<JwtBearerOptions>("JWT", 
            op => op.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false)
        // other setup
    ).Build();
```

Also it is possible to pass `null` instead of `"JWT"` as it written in [comments](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/src/PostConfigureOptions.cs#L47):

```
// Null name is used to configure all named options.
```