# Does setting `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` to `false` disable JWKS?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

When I'm configuring an aspnet core project for JWT validation, one of the options is `ValidateIssuerSigningKey`:

```cs
            .AddJwtBearer((options) =>
            {
                // ...
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new()
                {
                    // ...
                    // note: This guy right here.
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = jwtConfiguration.ValidateIssuerSigningKey,
                };
            });
```

My question: If I set `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` to `false`, will this disable JWKS?  Or does this option only apply in the scope of tokens that include their signing key?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/27371

Comment: According to the description of [this document](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/Use-of-TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuerSigningKey), `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` is not directly related to JWKS, it only seems to affect validation.

Comment: According to [Set's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49935695/18789859), if you want to disable validation at all，you can Set All `ValidateXXX` and `RequireXXX` bool properties to false. So, [ValidateIssuerSigningKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.validateissuersigningkey?view=azure-dotnet) only applies to default signing key validation.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. It says that it's validating the signing key, but from what source?

Comment: JWT encrypts user information into Token, and the server does not save any information. The server verifies the correctness of the Token by using the saved key, as long as it is correct, it can pass the verification. If enable `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` it will validate more information inside the key.

Comment: The `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` and `ValdiateIssuer` properties indicate that the token’s signature should be validated and that the key’s property indicating it’s issuer must match an expected value. You can check [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/) to view more details.

Comment: You're not addressing my specific concern.  I'm asking about whether `ValidateIssuerSigningKey` affects JWKS.